# Pass data from child to parent when navigating back with react router?

Tags: reactjs, undo

I know I can pass data when navigating forward with `Link`, `Route` ..

```
<Route
  path="/release"
  exact
  render={() => <ManagedEventsList pages={this.state.pages} />}
/>
```

witten here: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/

but is it possible to pass data also when browser back button was pressed?

This article show how to pass from state from `child` to `parent` without react router. Would it work with react router?

https://dev.to/zeyadetman/how-to-pass-state-between-components-in-reactjs-2pg1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `react-router-dom`, no, it isn't possible to pass state with a back navigation. The `history` object can only send state with `push` or `replace` actions. The `go` actions only update the pointer to the current location in the history stack, i.e. `go(-1)` is equivalent to `goBack()`.

If you need to preserve data correlated to the history stack or if you need to also "send" data during a back navigation then you'll need a library outside of `react-router-dom`. Redux would be a decent option, if you are already using it, to save in state either data used during navigation, or to along with doing a `history.goBack()` to also dispatch an action to save some "goBack" data in state to be retrieved via check on the previous page. Others like Redux Sagas or Thunks allow you to issue side-effects along with updating state. With these you could create your own `goBackWithState` action that saves some state in your Redux state *and then* issues the back navigation.

[react-router-dom history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)

Comment: In summary if I use `react-router-dom` I need to use `redux`?

Comment: No, they are separate and independent. I only assumed you were referencing `react-router-dom` (which uses `react-router`). The redux bit would be *a way* to pass "state" through your app. If you are not familiar with redux, other alternatives would be rolling your own react context provider (this is what redux uses, btw, just with a standard state update model), or going lo-fi and directly setting a value in the window object (not recommended). Point being, other options exist, just pick one that fits your needs.